# Python Return Statement Not Providing Expected Results

Tags: python, mysql, function, return-value

Just attempting to return values from a defined function. When calling the function first and attempting to print the return values I receive "[variable] not defined". However, if I run "print(qb_stat_filler())" it prints the results in a tuple. I need the individual variables returned to use in a separate function.

*For Example*
print(qb_stat_filler())
outputs: (0, 11, 24, 24.2024, 39.1143, 293.0, 1.9143000000000001, 0.2262, 97.84333355313255)

but when trying
qb_stat_filler()
print(cmp_avg)
print(att_avg)
outputs: NameError: name 'cmp_avg' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

I've tried establishing the variables outside of the function, then passing and returning them and that did not work either. Any thoughts?

```
        def qb_stat_filler():
                n_input = input('Player name: ')
                t_input = input('Players team: ')
                loc_input = input('H or @: ')
                o_input = input('Opponent: ')

                # convert index csv to dictionary of player values
                q = pd.read_csv('Models\\QB Indexes\\QBname.csv')
                q = q[['Player', 'Num']]
                qb_dict = dict(q.values)
                name = qb_dict.get('{}'.format(n_input))

                t = pd.read_csv('Models\\QB Indexes\\Tmname.csv')
                t = t[['Tm', 'Num']]
                tm_dict = dict(t.values)
                team = tm_dict.get('{}'.format(t_input))

                loc = 0
                if loc_input == '@':
                loc = 0
                elif loc_input == 'H':
                loc = 1

                z = pd.read_csv('Models\\QB Indexes\\Oppname.csv')
                z = z[['Opp', 'Num']]
                opp_dict = dict(z.values)
                opp = opp_dict.get('{}'.format(o_input))
                *there are several lines of code here that involve SQL 
                queries and data cleansing*
                cmp_avg = (cmp_match + cmpL4) / 2
                att_avg = (patt_match + pattL4) / 2
                pyds_avg = (py_match + pydsL4) / 2
                ptd_avg = (ptdL4 + ptd_match) / 2
                int_avg = (intL4 + int_match) / 2
                qbr_avg = (qbr_match + qbrL4) / 2
                return name, team, opp, cmp_avg, att_avg, pyds_avg, ptd_avg, 
                int_avg, qbr_avg


        qb_stat_filler()
```

Comment: Im not sure exactly how to do that. This function involves several queries to a database in order to work. I have tested the function it self about 50 times and it works without issue. Now that I have decided to abstract it away I simply cant get it to return the values I know its producing.

Comment: There's not enough of your code to make a judgement on this. For example, the variables *name* and *team* (and others) don't exist so you're bound to have problems

Comment: Sorry, I made some edits to add more code and example outputs. All of the variables mentioned exist and the function itself has been tested and worked before so I know that is not my issue. there are about 60 lines of code in between that return the variables I am averaging at the end.

Comment: `cmp_avg` and `att_avg` are local to the function.  They cease to exist when the function exits.  You are calling the function, but you are throwing away the information it returns.  You need something like `name, team, opp, cmp_avg, att_avg, pyds_avg, ptd_avt, int_avg, qbr_avg = qb_stat_filler()`, so you can create variables to store the data.  You might consider using a dictionary or an object, so you can expand the list later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider:

```
def qb_stat_filler():
    stats = {}
    ...
    stats['name'] = name
    z = z[['Opp', 'Num']]
    opp_dict = dict(z.values)
    stats['opp'] = opp_dict.get('{}'.format(o_input))
    ...
    stats['cmp_avg'] = (cmp_match + cmpL4) / 2
    stats['att_avg'] = (patt_match + pattL4) / 2
    stats['pyds_avg'] = (py_match + pydsL4) / 2
    stats['ptd_avg'] = (ptdL4 + ptd_match) / 2
    stats['int_avg'] = (intL4 + int_match) / 2
    stats['qbr_avg'] = (qbr_match + qbrL4) / 2
    return stats
...
stats = qb_stat_filler()
print(stats['cmp_avg'])
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked simply enough and I wont have to change any of my code that comes after that. Thanks a bunch Tim!

Comment: That's fine, but from a software engineering perspective, it makes it harder for you to improve things later.